# Smooth Vue Translation Transition Between Two Elements

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, transition

I'm working on a Vue animation where:

- Button #1 slides out to the left.
- Button #2 slides in to the right.

And vice-versa.

However, when I initiate the transition, Button #2 in inserted into the DOM, and immediately pushes Button #1 to the right, where #1 then begins its transition.

Here's my component:

```
<transition name="detail">
    <div class="u-align-center" v-if="showShare">
        <button class="btn btn-wide u-ml-20 u-mr-40 u-align-center u-text-blue">
            Sample Button
        </button>
    </div>
</transition>
<transition name="detail">
    <div class="u-align-center u-ml-20 u-mr-40" v-if="!showShare">
        <button class="btn btn-blue u-mr-20 u-align-center" @click="showDetail = !showDetail" v-if="!showDetail">
            See List
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-blue u-align-center u-mr-20" @click="showShare = !showShare" v-if="!showShare">
            Take With You
        </button>
    </div>
</transition>
```

And here's my CSS:

```
.detail-enter {
    transform: translateX(-2500px);
}

.detail-enter-to {
    transform: translateX(0px);
}

.detail-leave {
    transform: translateX(0px);
}

.detail-leave-to {
    transform: translateX(-2500px);
}

.detail-leave-active {
    transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(.42,0,.58,1);
}

.detail-enter-active {
    transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(.42,0,.58,1);
    transition-delay: .75s;
}
```

Here's a GIF of exactly what I'm experiencing:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9vg7c9mrvxt5pyr/gif.gif?dl=0

Is there a way to accomplish this with Vue Transitions? I've read about [transition modes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes), which seem to do exactly what I need, but I can't get them to behave in this context.

Comment: I don't see that you are using transition modes in your current code.  Can you update your example to show where and how you are trying to use them?

Comment: @zero298, I have two instances of a vue transition called `<transition name="detail">` in the component code above. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: can you make something on codesandbox instead? https://codesandbox.io/s/vue